# Angular child component variable not updating when called from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues dynamically updating an elements style.

I am overlaying some margins on top of an image. I created a child component to handle this. I call a function on my child component which calculates the margins and then sets a variable.

Here is the parent component call, which is triggered by a button click.

```
showMargins() {
    if (this.showingMargins) {

        this.showingMargins = false;
    } else {
        this.showingMargins = true;
        this.marginComponent.calculateMargins();
    }
}
```

And here is my child component:

```
marginStyles: any = {};
...
calculateMargins() {
    //logic 
    ...
    //set the property
    this.marginStyles = {
       'height.px': height,
       'margin-left.px': left
    }
}
```

And then in my template

```
<div id="margin-left" [ngStyle]="marginStyles">
```

I've tried using a function as well

```
private leftDiv() {
    debugger;
    return this.marginStyles;
}
```

thus changing my template to

```
<div id="margin-left" [ngStyle]="leftDiv()">
```

but to no avail. If I hardcode the values when I declare the variable it works fine.

```
    marginStyles: any = {'height.px': 200, 'margin-left.px': 20};
```

And if I hardcode it in the template it works fine as well; it's just failing after I've done my calculations and won't render the lines that I'm overlaying. Where have I gone wrong? If it helps, I'm on Angular 4.

Edit: I moved all of my logic to my parent component, and everything looks fine. It appears to me that the values I am for `marginStyle` are not being updated in the child component, which is baffling to me.  They should be updating. ngStyle is working fine, it's the variable that is not being updated.

Comment: Where the function `calculateMargins()` is called?

Comment: that is being called by the parent component.

Comment: Could you provide small demo on https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular ?

Comment: return this.leftMarginStyles; or return this.marginStyles; ?

Comment: Try showing the style in the view with `<div>{{ marginStyles | json }}</div>`. It may not be in a valid state (`height` and `left` may not be valid numbers in your code).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I tried doing that, but I end up with the empty object that I initialized at the beginning. :(

Comment: You can then use `console.log` in `showMargins` and in `calculateMargins` to see if the functions are called and behave as you expect.

Comment: this.marginStyles = {  'height': height+'px', 'margin-left': left+'px'  }???

Comment: @ConnorsFan The functions are all being called correctly, it just appears that the marginStyles variable isn't updating in the UI. I confirmed that it's being set correctly but it's not reflecting that in the UI when I use my calculated values or when I hard code simple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented the similar code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvayak

and it seems to be working as expected. Please, check for the differences.
Pay attention to the Element referencing by means of `ViewChild` decorator, all functions should be public, `ElementRef` type is the referencing component class because of typization.

Comment: Beat me to it, that's essentially what I am doing.

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference in my source code vs what we've implemented in stackblitz, which is confusing to me why it'd work there but not in my project

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return `marginStyles` instead of `leftMarginStyles`